# Is it normal to have cli listening on port 41049?

Tags: networking

I never knew that `cli` (command line interface) needs a port to listen to. Why would command line interface need a `tcp` port open? Is `cli` something else?

Is it normal to have this port open on my Ubuntu 16.04?

Here is my `netstat` output:

```
$ sudo netstat -ntlp
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      959/mysqld      
    tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1474/dnsmasq    
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      932/sshd        
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41049         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4811/cli        
    tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1058/apache2    
    tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      932/sshd
```

I'm fine with the other ports because I need apache, `ssh` and `mysql`. After googling I found that it is normal to have `dnsmasq` but nothing about `cli`.

Comment: No it's not normal. What's the output of this command `ps -o args= -p "$(sudo lsof -t -i:41049)"`

Comment: No, this doesn't seem to be normal. The output gives you the PID of that process, 4811.  Have you looked at the process information ? What does `cat /proc/4811/cli` tell you ?  what does  `lsof -p 4811` tell you ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, it gives me this "ps -o args= -p "$(sudo lsof -t -i:41049)".

Comment: @ali76, I have keepass2 installed and it seems it is because of that. I am wondering why it opens tcp port. Its intended use is just to generate and store passwords locally. The outout of the command you gave me is: "/usr/bin/cli /usr/lib/keepass2/KeePass.exe". And when I close keepass that port is not open anymore. after closing and opening again it uses another port.

Comment: @KarimMtl please click the edit button below your post, and paste exactly what each command gives you into your original post

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, I am sorry I just noticed the copy paste error.  cat /proc/4811/cli ->cat: /proc/4811/cli: No such file or directory and the other command gives me output too big to copy paste here. it starts with this: COMMAND   PID USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
cli     18557   me  cwd       DIR              179,2     4096  934561 /home/me
cli     18557   me  rtd       DIR              179,2     4096       2 /
cli     18557   me  txt       REG              179,2  3491512  934569 /usr/bin/mono-sgen

Comment: It's know bug for it's description please look at this link : http://git.net/ml/general/2016-10/msg40787.html

Comment: I'm trying to install this package now and then looking at `sudo netstat -ntlp` result .  `cli` listen to `40967 ` port like you. So it's normal to `cli` is listening to your port

Comment: @ali76, thank you very much for your help. keepass2 is not part of ubuntu official packages I added its ppa myself. Do you think it still safe to use or better not? Also could you please post your answer as an answer not a comment so that I can accept it to help other people with similar issue.

Comment: Which distribution do you have ? I'm having this package in `zesty` official repo's

Comment: you can install this package with this command without any ppa `sudo apt install keepass2` this package is available in `xenial` , `trusty` , `yakkety` and `zesty` repos because of this link : https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/keepass2

Comment: @ali76I, you are right I think I did not need to because it does not show source.list. Thanks

Comment: @KarimMtl As you said , I've post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For check which process is listening on `41049` port you can run this command:

```
ps -o args= -p "$(sudo lsof -t -i:41049)"
```

As you said in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921623/is-it-normal-to-have-cli-listening-on-port-41049?noredirect=1#comment1455599_921623), the output is refer to `keepass2` package. So look around this package:

I'm trying to install this package and check the output:

```
sudo apt install keepass2
```

And the output of `sudo netstat -ntlp` is:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40967         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8393/cli
```

So after installing `keepass2`, `cli` is listening on local `TCP` port.

So, your outputs is quite normal.

---

Really I don't know why `keepass2` is listening on this port. But it's may be a bug. For its description you can look at this [link](http://git.net/ml/general/2016-10/msg40787.html) .

---

But because of that , `keepass2` is available in Ubuntu's official repositories , it cannot be a threat for you.

You can see this package description on [Ubuntu package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/keepass2).